# I use the function emailjs.send to send email. Why it shows https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send 422

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';


async function sendEmail() {
  try {
    const serviceID = '...'; 
    const templateID = '...'; 
    const userID = '...'; 

    const emailParams = {
      to_email: '...', 
      from_name: 'Your Name', 
      message: 'Hello, this is the email content.' 
    };
    
    const response = await emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, emailParams, userID);
    console.log(response)
    console.log('Email sent successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to send email:', error);
    console.log("??")
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={sendEmail}>Send</button>
    </>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Filed to send email: EmailJSResponseStatus {status: 422, text: 'The recipient address is empty'}

But the function emailjs.sendForm can work.

How should correct my code?

Answer (score 1):

Replace 'to_email' with 'user_email'.